# Rewrite Web API 2 Url

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7, asp.net-web-api2

First! I'm sorry because my English not good.
I'm using MVC 5 and Web API 2 in one solution.

My Web Api has url :

```
http://example.com/api/controller/id
```

Now, I want change it to :

```
http://api.example.com/controller/id
```

Please help me.

Comment: Did you try to edit the _`RouteConfig.cs`_?

Comment: Thanks for help. What can i do with RouteConfig file?

Comment: You can edit the default routing allowed there, to change the Url Routing in ASP.NET.

Comment: You can check http://grandhah.blogspot.in/2015/07/url-rewriting-in-mvc-4-attribute-routing.html for detailed url writing in web-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `WebApiConfig.cs`, change the route specified in the `Register` function from this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

to this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Notice I removed `api/` from the `routeTemplate`.

A quick cautionary: The reason Web API serves under the `/api/` path is to help you avoid name clashes with MVC controllers. So use at your own peril.